# Google Page Speed says avoid meta tag for char set, but I haven't used a meta tag for that

Tags: performance, character-encoding, google-pagespeed

**Using Google Page Speed**, I get a message, "*Avoid a character set in the meta tag*," with a link to a [page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#SpecifyCharsetEarly) which tells me all about why I shouldn't use a meta tag to define the character set.

But my pages (WordPress) don't specify the character set in the meta tag.  Instead I've done it by placing this at the top of the theme's `header.php`:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

My questions are:

1. is my method of specifying the character set correct ?
2. if it is, why is Google's PageSpeed tool complaining about a non-existent meta tag specification ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTML code of your page, as sent to browsers and other user agents. (E.g., use View Source when viewing the page in a browser.) The odds are that there is a `meta` tag that declares character encoding (“character set”). It might be generated by the authoring software you’re using.

In my tests, the only way to trigger the message when using https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/ was to prevent a server from sending encoding information in HTTP and to include a `meta` tag for it. It is understandable in such a setting that performance may be degraded.

Otherwise, the advice from Google Page Speed in this issue is bad advice. You *should* declare the encoding in a `meta` tag *in addition to* declaring it in HTTP headers, as the page might be saved locally  in that case, when the local copy is opened, there won’t be any HTTP headers.

Comment: I've thoroughly checked the page source, and there is no meta tag anywhere that declares the character encoding.  But you're saying Google's wrong anyway (as well as seemingly wrong about the warning)?

Comment: @JohnDoe, consider posting a URL. There might be something special that causes the message, or maybe the server sends different data to different user agents.

Comment: If you look at this test page you can see that Google reports incorrectly: http://mozzaic.co.uk/test.php

Comment: @JohnDoe, when I test it, https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fmozzaic.co.uk_2Ftest.php&mobile=false i get a PageSpeed Score of 100 (out of 100). Clicking on the link “Already done! (29)”, I see a list of items, starting with “Avoid a character set in the meta tag”, with content “PageSpeed Insights has no suggestions for this page. Good job!”

Comment: You would get that score, since there's hardly anything on the page.  The page is there purely to demonstrate that Google Page Speed will complain about the use of a meta tag to set the character set, despite the fact that such a tag doesn't exist.

Comment: @JohnDoe, so what exactly do you get as a complaint? The text “Avoid a character set in the meta tag” is in the “Already done!” section (and without a link).

Comment: On Firefox Mac Page Speed doesn't seem to show any 'already done' section but after all the green ticks shows "information" icons on things like "Avoid a character set in the meta tag" as if to say, everything's OK except pay attention to this.  Sorry if I'm reading it all wrong!

Comment: @JohnDoe, I suppose it’s just a misleading feature in Firefox Mac Page Speed.